# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException Error creating bean (repository)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot/MySQL/docker project. After adding the repository classes, I started getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'filterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filterService': 
Error creating bean with name 'filterServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filterRepository': 
No qualifying bean of type 'backend.challenge.repositories.FilterRepository' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Checked my classes and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511/unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-with-name), annotated everything.
There are two repositories, I'll just post one:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<FilterEntity, String> {}
```

Service:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface FilterService {
    FilterResponseDto createFilter(FilterRequestDto filterRequestDto);
    List<FilterResponseDto> getAllFilters();
}
```

Service implementation:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class FilterServiceImpl implements FilterService{
    @Autowired
    private FilterRepository filterRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FilterChangelogRepository filterChangelogRepository;

    //method implementations here
}
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("filters")
@Validated
public class FilterController {
    @Autowired
    private FilterService filterService;
    //mappings here
}
```

application.properties (pointing to the MySQL db running on docker)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/challenge
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Lastly, my dependency list which is quite a mess:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Would appreciate if anybody could share some thoughts on this.

Edit1: cleaned dependencies, still getting the same error.

Edit2: Adding docker-compose file:

```
services:

  yourapp:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: challenge
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 5
```

Comment: For what it's worth, some thoughts to think about. First, I find it a bit strange to have @Service on both the FilterService and FilterServiceImpl. I would only put it on the implementation class... Second, why so many dependencies like spring-tx, javax.transaction-api, javax.persistence, etc. Those should all be provided by the spring-data-jpa dependency. I recommend cleaning up those dependencies to exclude conflicting packages as a possible cause... I guess leaving the starters and mysql-connector should be sufficient...

Comment: @KDW javax.persistence, for instance, is for my Entity classes. I want to have some transactions, that's why I have spring-tx, javax.transaction-api. Is spring-data-jpa dependency enough for what I want to achieve?

Comment: Since you are using Spring Boot in your application, you only need to define the following dependencies for database access. tx, persintence, etc is part of the starter dependency.       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Is the mentioned error message the entire stacktrace?
Your db is running in Docker, is it accessible on the application.properties uri using e.g. MySQL Workbench? Does your application run in a Docker container as well, or does it run in your IDE?

Comment: This may be caused when the repository is not scanned - maybe your `@SpringBootApplication` class is in different package - to make it work, it has to be in the same or any parent package

Comment: did you enable jpa repositories using @EnableJpaRepositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon much trial and error and after fixing my dependencies as @KDW suggested, I finally figured out what was wrong.
I created my project from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with version 3.0.2. Turns out there are some issues as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73331089/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type-class-com-sportyshoe-ent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674544/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type-entity).
Also, I was missing some annotations on my main class.
Here's my solution:

Step 1 - Downgrade Spring Boot version from 3.0.2 to 2.7.8:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Step 2 - Dependency list

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Step 3 - Annotations on main class

```
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories("package_with_my_repositories")
@EntityScan("package_with_my_entities")
@SpringBootApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace your dependencies with the following.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.19.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you run your Spring Boot application inside your IDE or as a non-containerized application on the same host as your Docker engine, try using `localhost` instead of the container name.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/challenge
```

Comment: Adding spring-boot-starter-data-jpa adds HikariCP and I'm getting a new error now: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')

Regarding docker, I've added my docker-compose in the original post.

Comment: Looks like a configuration issue/conflict. Would it be possible by any chance to share your code somewhere on a Git repository?